# Excluding log4j.properties in rampart module

Tags: maven, log4j, rampart

I have a maven project in which I am using axis2 which depends on rampart-core for security.
Rampart has a default log4j.properties file which keeps my logging from being displayed. I would like to exclude that file from my dependency. How do I exclude a file from a dependency while still keeping the dependency around?

Answer (score 0):

As a solution you can of course unpack the dependency (using the [maven-dependencies-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/)), remove the properties file and repack the dependency (using the [maven-assembly-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/)) and later depend on the repackaged artifact instead.

I find this whole process too cumbersome actually. Why aren't you just provide your own log4j.properties in src/main/resources to override the contained file?

Comment: Customizaing my `src/main/resources/log4j.properties` does not alter how sshd-core logs. :(

Comment: Did you check your class-path order?

Comment: Yeah, `mvn test -X` shows my project's classes and resources at the head of the classpath.